# Why interval not work after ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know why after I click button but interval not work in HTML. I use angularJS to get count in every second. I just want interval start after click button.

This **HTML**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="start()"><span>Start {{hitung}}</span></button>
```

And this **JS**

```
$scope.hitung = 0;
$scope.start= function () {                    
  var auto = $interval(function () {
    $scope.hitung++;
  }, 1000);
};
```

I try this but interval not work and `$scope.hitung always 0`. If any one have solution please tell me it will really help me.

Thanks

Comment: can you show more of your code? because your code you show here is working fine. It might maybe because you missing out the `ng-controller ` or other things.

Comment: Yeah @Dean you are right. Thanks has reminded me :D

Comment: If @Dean has given you an answer, please mark this question as answered / resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution using a more modern style of AngularJS development (needs AngularJS v1.5 or greater):

```js
angular.module('stackoverflow', [])
  .component('counter', {
    template: '<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.start()"><span>Start {{$ctrl.hitung}}</span></button>',
    controller: ['$interval', function CounterCtrl($interval) {
      var self = this;
      this.hitung = 0;

      var interval;
      var cancelInterval = function() {
        if (!interval) return;
        $interval.cancel(interval);
        interval = null;
      };
      this.start = function() {
        cancelInterval();
        interval = $interval(function() {
          self.hitung++;
        }, 1000);
      };
      this.$onDestroy = function() {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
      };
    }]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="stackoverflow">
  <counter></counter>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$scope.hitung = 0;
$scope.start= function () {                    
   $interval(function () {
       $scope.hitung++;
   }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: explain why? what is different?

Answer (score 0):

I check your code and found it's working good.Maybe you miss an argument ie `$interval` in the `controllers` control.

**Try to add the $interval as follow...**

```
//There app is an `angular.module` and `myCtrl` is a `controller` 

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
        $scope.hitung = 0;
        $scope.start= function () {                    
          var auto = $interval(function () {
            $scope.hitung++;
          }, 1000);
        };
    });
```